# Migration to .net 6 Unable to load ICU library

Tags: c#, devexpress, .net-6.0, icu

I am getting this error

```
Exception message: Unable to load ICU library.;
Inner exception: ;
StackTrace: at DevExpress.Text.Interop.ICUInterop.LoadSharedLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader libraryLoader)
at DevExpress.Text.Interop.ICUInterop.<>c.<.cctor>b__9_0()
```

during converting html to pdf in my app after migration to .Net 6

I am running .NET 6.0.7 in docker container alpine.3.16-x64

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0.7-alpine3.16

ARG APP_DIRECTORY

WORKDIR /app

RUN apk add --no-cache harfbuzz-icu ttf-opensans && \
    apk add --no-cache --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main libcrypto1.0 libssl1.0 && \
    apk add --no-cache --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing libgdiplus-dev && \
    apk add --no-cache icu icu-libs icu-dev icu-data-full icu-static icu-doc harfbuzz-icu harfbuzz-dev && \
    rm -rf /tmp/* /var/cache/apk/*
    
ENV DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=true
```

My runtimeconfig.json

```
{
  "configProperties": {
    "System.Drawing.EnableUnixSupport": true,
    "System.Globalization.Invariant": true
  }
}
```

Does anybody faced the same problem during upgrading from 5.0 to 6.0?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in ICU library. Alpine3.16 has icu version 71

https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/releases/tag/release-71-1

So we downgraded to alpine3.15 which has icu version 69 and everything works.